# How to encode HTTP response bytes in UTF-8 correctly?

Tags: http, go, utf-8

After making an HTTP request using `http` package, I'm reading a response:

```
    resp, _ := client.Do(request)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    responseBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    log.Println("body", string(responseBody))
```

The response is in JSON format, containing Russian characters, so I see in console

```
{"error_code":201,"error_name":"\u041f\u043e\u043b ... "}
```

How can I decode response bytes so that I see readable message?

Comment: Use the [encoding/json package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal), of course.

Comment: Your response is JSON, so process it as JSON and print the `error_name` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON decoder in Go can deal with encoded symbols, you need to unmarshal payload in struct or other value:

https://play.golang.org/p/Mt-phU4kxfy

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    payload := []byte(`{"error_code":201,"error_name":"\u041f\u043e\u043b ... "}`)
    var p interface{}

    _ = json.Unmarshal(payload, &p)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", p) // map[string]interface {}{"error_code":201, "error_name":"Пол ... "}

    var e struct {
        ErrorCode int    `json:"error_code"`
        ErrorName string `json:"error_name"`
    }

    _ = json.Unmarshal(payload, &e)
    fmt.Println(e.ErrorCode, e.ErrorName) // 201 Пол ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might be enough for me just to have a string response, but it seems for UTF8 characters it's not enough. JSON unmarshalling helps here.

Comment: If you'd just sent string, not JSON, Go would also correctly handle it. But in JSON UTF8 needs to be correctly escaped. This is part of the JSON specification: https://www.json.org/json-en.html